# How can I implement 2-factor authentication in FreeRADIUS?

Tags: freeradius

I have successfully performed an ID/PW authentication test using FreeRADIUS's PAP.

When I receive ID/PW and OTP as a request from the client, I want to first authenticate the ID/PW using PAP. If the initial authentication is successful, I then wish to proceed with the second authentication using OTP, which involves communication with my personal authentication server through REST.

I have added the information for the second authentication API in the "post-auth" section of the rest file, and I have also added the following code to the "post-auth" section of the default configuration file.

```
post-auth {

    update control {
            Auth-Type := rest
    }
    rest
    ... 
}
```

It works as expected, but in my opinion, "post-auth" feels like it should be executed after all authentications are completed.

I don't think I should perform the second authentication in "post-auth," but I haven't been able to find another solution.

Would proceeding this way cause any issues?

If you have a better alternative, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

years a go I played with Freeradius with rlm_rest using django as the-backend. This system is for handling mikrotik hotspot login.

My scenario is forcing a centralized login screen.
The internal mikrotik hotspot login.html redirect user to mylogin.
After succesfull web login, my djanggo will silently create a record in memcached that have a username and random password and set it to be expired in 5 secs

the django also create a reply to user consist of prepopulated html form that auto-post to mikrotik.

Mikrotik will do authentication to freeradius using that username and randomize password.

Inturn, freeradius will request my django, and django will answer based on data stored in memcached. and set the memcached expired.

By default, mikrotik hotspot login page is http .. not encrypted but my django page is http.
So ... if there is someone make an ether dump at the last step of login, it's useless ... since the randomize password will no longer valid.